# KVM Switch to handle USB-C, Video & Power

Tags: usb, kvm, hub

I'm trying to set up the following: two computers (MBP15 w/ USB-C and a desktop) that feed into one monitor and share USB peripherals (mouse, keyboard, hub, etc). I've found a few switches that seem to do what I need but I was hoping for some expert advice (product/brand recommendations?) before I pull the trigger.

Diagram for clarity:

[image: Diagram for Clarity]